# How To Use Vuejs With Nodejs Express and Mongodb for a login and signup app

Tags: node.js, express, web, vue.js

**How will i use passport and jwt token to achieve this all the while but its not working**

```
router.post('/login' , 
    passport.authenticate('local' , {
        failureRedirect: "/sss",
        // failureFlash:true
  }), function(req,res){
      res.send({
          status: true,
          messasge: "Login Succesful" + user,      
      });          
});
```

Comment: please explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: the entire process and because i am using a vuejs on another file and using express js on another file i don't know how to redirect it yet or do you have any example